# List of d3 symbols available to us

Tags: javascript, d3.js, symbols

Where can I find the list of symbols made available to us by d3.js  which is referred by this line of code:

```
 d3.svg.symbol().type(/*Name of the symbol type that is available to us to use*/'triangle')
```

Some of the available symbols include triangle, diamond. Is there any documentation available anywhere where the entire list is documented.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For version 4, there are seven shapes, as opposed to the six in version 3 (referenced in the other answer).

The shapes are contained in the array `d3.symbols` which contains:

- `d3.symbolCircle`
- `d3.symbolCross`
- `d3.symbolDiamond`
- `d3.symbolSquare`
- `d3.symbolStar` (new in version 4)
- `d3.symbolTriangle` (there is only one triangle in v 4, compared to 2 in v3)
- `d3.symbolWye` (a 'y' shaped symbol, new in version 4)

The d3 documentation as usual covers [the topic well here](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#symbols).

To show the symbols, and to show how the array can be used to set shapes dynamically, I've attached a snippet below:

```js
var data = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6];
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width',400).attr('height',200);

svg.selectAll('.symbol')
   .data(data)
   .enter()
   .append('path')
   .attr('transform',function(d,i) { return 'translate('+(i*20+20)+','+30+')';})
   .attr('d', d3.symbol().type( function(d,i) { return d3.symbols[i];}) );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.5.0/d3.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you explain, how does this 2 lines work ?
` .attr('transform',function(d,i) { return 'translate('+(i*20+20)+','+30+')';})
   .attr('d', d3.symbol().type( function(d,i) { return d3.symbols[i];}) );`

Comment: When you see `function(d,i)` in a selection like this, you are accessing the datum and increment associated with each element in the selection. So in the first line, the symbol is positioned 30 pixels down, and i*20+20 pixel from the left. The second line returns a d3 symbol type, as `d3.symbols` is an array, we can use the increment to select a specific symbol.

Comment: Actually I'm only trying to create one symbol
Is this the right way to do ?
`var svg = d3.select('svg').attr('width',400).attr('height',200);
svg.append('path')
   .attr('transform','translate(50,80)')
   .attr('d', d3.symbol().type( function(d) { return d3.symbols[2];}) )`
and also, I'm trying to create drag & drop on symbol can you help me with the approach?

Comment: Yes, though `d3.select('body').append('svg')` might be what you are intending. As for drag and drop, that's too much for a comment and too different from the question to be added to the answer. It might already exist as a question, or it needs to be asked as one.

Comment: can you answer this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38586717/d3js-on-angularjs-how-to-drag-and-drop-component-and-link-them-with-connector-u) ?

Comment: +1 this demonstration is so much simpler as a bare bones example than the official D3 Symbol documentation for generating symbols

Answer (score 15):

The types supported are listed in the D3 documentation: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#symbol_type. To quote:

> > - circle - a [circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle).
> > - cross - a [Greek cross](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross) or plus sign.
> > - diamond - a [rhombus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombus).
> > - square - an axis-aligned [square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_%28geometry%29).
> > - triangle-down - a downward-pointing [equilateral triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equilateral_triangle).
> > - triangle-up - an upward-pointing equilateral triangle.

D3 also has an object that stores the symbols available (thanks again, @jshanley). E.g. for D3 3.4.6:

```
>>> d3.svg.symbolTypes
["circle", "cross", "diamond", "square", "triangle-down", "triangle-up"]
```

Comment: You can also use [`d3.svg.symbolTypes`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#symbolTypes) to return an array of the types supported in your version of d3.

Comment: Cool, thanks :) I was wondering if there are more symbol types available or just these 6? :(

Comment: This is no longer the correct answer. @Andrew Reid's is.