# D3Js on angularjs: How to drag and drop component and link them with connector using mouse

Tags: angularjs, d3.js

I want to develop sample application based the below conditions using D3JS and angularjs.
For example.
I have left pane and right pane.
i have some nodes on left pane.(nodes can be any shapes or icons)
i want to drag the nodes from left to right and join the specific nodes using connector.
Thanks.