# Change symbol for graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph-visualization

I want to change the symbol type from circle to triangle, square, other symbols.

```
svg.selectAll().
data(data).enter()
.append("circle")
.attr("class", "dot")
.attr("cx", function(d, i) { return timeScale(d.year); })
.attr("cy", function(d, i) { return yScale(d.sale) })
.style("fill", "#FFC300")
.attr("r", function(d) {return est_size(d.est)})
```

If I change `.append("circle")` to `.append("triangle")`, the chart does not show the symbol. How can I show a triangle instead of a circle?

Comment: How have you modified the above code to show another symbol?

Comment: changed .append("circle") to "triangle"

Comment: have you looked at d3 symbol? https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#symbol

Answer (score 1):

SVG doesn't have an element type for a `triangle` - the most basic shapes are `rect` and `circle` (there are also paths, polygons, ellipses, etc, but no triangle). However, we have a few options open to us, we can use a d3-symbol (available symbols listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24539234/7106086)), or we can create our own symbol and use that.

For using d3-symbol we can do the following:

```js
var width = 500;
var height = 300;
var data = d3.range(10)
  .map(function(d) { return { x: Math.random()*width, y: Math.random()*height }; })
  
var svg = d3.select("svg")
  .attr("width",width)
  .attr("height",height);
  
svg.selectAll(".symbol")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolTriangle).size(50))
  .attr("transform",function(d) { return "translate("+[d.x,d.y]+")" })
  .attr("class","symbol");

// For demonstrating that the triangles are centered:
svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 3)
  .attr("fill","orange")
  .attr("transform",function(d) { return "translate("+[d.x,d.y]+")" });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

*symbol.size corresponds to shape area, not an edge length*

Alternatively, we can create a function that returns a basic triangle polygon ourselves, and use it with `selection.append()`:

```js
var width = 500;
var height = 300;
var data = d3.range(10)
  .map(function(d) { return { x: Math.random()*width, y: Math.random()*height }; })
  
var svg = d3.select("svg")
  .attr("width",width)
  .attr("height",height);
  
var symbol = function() {
  // Hand drawn triangle:
  return d3.create('svg:path').attr("d","M0,8L-5,-3L5,-3Z").node()
}
    
  
svg.selectAll(".symbol")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append(symbol) // append can accept a function.
  .attr("transform",function(d) { return "translate("+[d.x,d.y]+")" })
  .attr("class","symbol");

// For demonstrating that the triangles are centered:
svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 3)
  .attr("fill","orange")
  .attr("transform",function(d) { return "translate("+[d.x,d.y]+")" });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

We could also take a few other approaches, such as using svg `symbol` elements, but the above two methods should be sufficient.

Comment: I tried using the svg.selectAll(".symbol") code that you used. it adds a single triangle on the y-axis.
How can I use the code I have for circles with other type of symbols?
It is supposed graph data for years and sale into a line chart, then size each point with  with estimated profit (d.est).

Comment: If you aren't using a transform with a translation as above, all the triangles will be placed the same on top of each other. But without seeing your code, I can't say why you have this issue, asking a new question about why the positioning is off is probably best..